# CSS - section with transparen image

Tags: html, css, image

Can someone please explain me, how I do something like this in the picture below?
It's a section in HTML, CSS but with an transparent image overlay.

Thank you for the help!

["picture below"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf9H7.png)

Here's a Link to the live page. Just click on "preview": https://yootheme.com/themes/finch

Comment: They are using three background images.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. If you have a specific problem add a relevant code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a "png" file image texture, and set as a background image for the div at the bottom of the slider based on your example. then add a negative margin-top to it. if the slider overlapped the div with the texture just add a z-index value.

```
.your-div{
background-image:url('your-image.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center-center;
margin-top:-25px;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I've tried something like this before but it doesn't work on my way. Your answer works!